# JavaFX auto resize panel 2 when panel 1 is not showing

Tags: javafx, javafx-8, javafx-2

When panel 1 is show.
[image: sample 1]

When panel 1 is not show.

[image: sample 2:]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply use a `VBox` and set the `vgrow` properties of the panels to `ALWAYS`:

```
@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
    CheckBox cb = new CheckBox("Show panel 1");
    cb.setSelected(true);

    // init panels
    Region panel1 = new Region();
    Region panel2 = new Region();
    panel1.setStyle("-fx-background-color: blue;");
    panel2.setStyle("-fx-background-color: red;");
    panel1.setPrefSize(300, 200);
    panel2.setPrefSize(300, 200);

    VBox root = new VBox(cb, panel1, panel2);

    // set VBox resizing properties
    VBox.setVgrow(panel1, Priority.ALWAYS);
    VBox.setVgrow(panel2, Priority.ALWAYS);
    VBox.setVgrow(cb, Priority.NEVER);

    // add/remove panel1 on CheckBox selection change
    cb.selectedProperty().addListener((obs, oldVal, newVal) -> {
        if (newVal) {
            root.getChildren().add(1, panel1);
        } else {
            root.getChildren().remove(panel1);
        }
    });

    Scene scene = new Scene(root);
    primaryStage.setScene(scene);
    primaryStage.show();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
pane2.prefWidthProperty().bind(
    Bindings.when(pane1.visibleProperty())
             .then(parent.widthProperty().subtract(pane1.widthProperty()))
             .otherwise(parent.widthProperty())
);

pane2.prefHeightProperty().bind(
    Bindings.when(pane1.visibleProperty())
             .then(parent.heightProperty().subtract(pane1.heightProperty()))
             .otherwise(parent.heightProperty())
);
```

This is assuming:

1. Your parent pane and Pane1 has a defined size (non-computed size).
2. None of the 3 panes has any padding.
3. Neither of the child panes have margin.